# Posting XML back to server Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

As i have never done this before I was wondering if anyone could either point out some resources that show best practices when dealing with XML (post/puts requests) or perhaps show an example.

for example i am trying to post back some XML to the [google contacts api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts) to update a contact

What i currently do is save the incoming XML into my model, edit functionality is performed within the app and then saved back to the model.Once everything is updated I then want to post back the updated contact back to the api in XML format, at present i only update the email address and persons name

Which is a PUTS request to

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/full/{contactId}
```

Could someone offer up an example of how they would do it?

The XML to be returned is

```
PUT /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/<var>contactId</var>
If-Match: <var>Etag</var>

<entry gd:etag='<var>Etag</var>'>
<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<var>userEmail</var>/base/<var>contactId</var></id>
<updated>2008-02-28T18:47:02.303Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
<gd:name>
<gd:givenName>New</gd:givenName>
<gd:familyName>Name</gd:familyName>
<gd:fullName>New Name</gd:fullName>
</gd:name>
<content type='text'>Notes</content>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*'
href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/<var>userEmail</var>/<var>contactId</var>'/>
 <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<var>userEmail</var>/full/<var>contactId</var>'/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml'
href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<var>userEmail</var>/full/<var>contactId</var>'/>
<gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other'
primary='true'>456-123-2133</gd:phoneNumber>
<gd:extendedProperty name='pet' value='hamster'/>
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false'
href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/<var>userEmail</var>/base/<var>groupId</var>'/>
</entry>
</pre>
```

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [Google Data on Rails](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails) project?

Comment: thanks, what is acl_entry = <<-EOF and still unsure how that fits in with updating a contact via the api? sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the google contacts API, but to POST/PUT/GET in Rails is quite simple using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or similar.

In HTTParty I'm pretty sure it's something like:

```
require 'httparty'
response = HTTParty.put("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/full/{contactId}",
             :body => { :xml => xml_data })
```

Comment: ah ok, so xml_data is the xml object that i have created? so its creating the xml object that i am unsure on

Comment: I don't know what data you're trying to send or what data the third-party service is expecting, but essentially yes, `xml_data` in my example is expected to be a string of XML data.

Comment: ive added the example xml they are expecting as an example, would you mind taking a look, offer some thoughts on the process please

Comment: just put it in a string. I'd recommend using a gem though if there is one which it looks as though there is from @d_ethier's comment.

Comment: thanks, if i wanted to add headers to the request could i just add :headers => { } after the body? comma separated of course, unless you could provide an example?

Comment: correct, there's examples [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty)